# Remote debug Jetty (no mvn, no plugins)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jetty, remote-debugging

***Past scenario***

 - Work with Tomcat and start in **debug mode** and **Remote Debug** with Eclipse.
 - Define a port and connect with eclipse in this debug/remote port.
 - Use to debug servers in other hosts/servers

***Today scenario***

Now, I'm using **Jetty** and I've try to do the same, but with no success, could anyone help-me with that?

I did not use Maven, and did not want to start Jetty inside from my Eclipse.

***Environment:***

Windows XP
Java V. 5
Jetty V. 6.1.15

***Links:***
http:// docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging
This did not help me!
http:// docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Debugging+Jetty+with+Eclipse
http:// neelzone.wordpress.com/2007/06/18/jetty-and-eclipse-integration
These are to start **inside** Eclipse

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is what we are adding to our JBoss command line while development:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then we launch the eclipse remote debugging and connection to this port.

---

**Update:**

To run from jar (standalone) do the following

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8585,server=y,suspend=n -jar start.jar
```

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: that syntax is for pre-1.5 JVMs, newer ones use the -agentlib:jdwp option.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your answer, works for me. I'm using the fallow command to start my Jetty:
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8585,server=y,suspend=n -jar start.jar

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

For remote debugging you should use [JPDA](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/index.jsp). There's a sort of tutorialish article about it available [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6139512.html).

In short, start your JVM with the argument:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
```

and you are able to connect to the underlying JVM listening on port 8000 via the standard Eclipse debugger.

Comment: If you are debugging server startup operations remember to set suspend=y

Answer (score 15):

If you will use **mvn jetty:run** one day, you have to

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

appending `-Xdebug ...` doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Using the JVM "agentlib" command-line parameter before "start.jar" did not work for me, but this does:

How to allow Eclipse to remotely debug #Jetty (#JPDA #agentlib:jdwp) on port 8000

You have to create a file, ***$JETTY_BASE/start.ini*** (do not change *$JETTY_HOME/start.ini*) and put the following two lines in it:

- **--exec**
- -**agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=n**

Comment: Exactly the same issue. Have to append lines to start.ini. Is there anyone know why?