# Debug web app in IntelliJ, webapp built by maven, run by jetty

Tags: debugging, web-applications, intellij-idea, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using s/o code, it's a java webapp built by maven. The webapp is run by maven script, like below, and the app is run on localhost:8080, :

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.8.v20121106</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <!--<port>8085</port>-->
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8089</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>            
        </plugins>
</build>
```

I want to attach the debugger of IntelliJ so that I can step through the code. I tried to set up a debugger configuration like: Jetty Server, then 'Remote' but it said Application Server not specified. I also tried with 'Local', it said 'main config file not included'.

So what must I do to attach the debugger?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835111/104891.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The easiest way is to:

1. Expand your project in the `Maven Projects` tab.
2. Expand `Plugins` > `jetty` items.
3. Right-click `jetty:run`.
4. Choose `Debug` from the context menu.

[image: screen shot of "Maven Projects" panel, context-menu to run Jetty in debug mode]

Comment: How do you make this a run configuration?

Comment: I can vouch for this approach with IntelliJ 2018.2 on macOS.

Answer (score 11):

I know it's too late to reply this question, but It's worth sharing the latest update on this issue as a modern solution: You can also run jetty using “`mvnDebug jetty:run`” which has the same effect. Which display the following logs in the terminal

```
Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

Just remember to choose the correct socket address(e.g. 8000), then:

1. Open Intellij
2. Run -> Edit Configuration
3. In Run/Debug Configuration window, you need to click on (+) button to add a new configuration
4. Select Remote
5. Keep the default configuration as is, just change the listening port to corresponding one (8000).

Enjoy.

Comment: It's never too late to reply to a question (well, to an on-topic question), as long as the answer is good.

Comment: Definitely this should be the best answer

Comment: This is definitely the best answer for the case when the one needs remote debugging!

Comment: @sergpank, I'm happy to see this answer is helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

When I was getting "main config file not included" it was because the path to Jetty in my Application Server configuration (on Run/Debug Configurations dialog) was deleted during my OS X upgrade (I had put it in /usr/share/java).

I reinstalled jetty-hightide-8.1.5.v20120716 under /usr/local, updated the configuration and all is well.