# How to debug my web app which runs on jetty server?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jetty

I have a code base, which has a java client and a flex client.

The java client is debugged easily. But how can I debug my flex client which starts after starting the jetty server?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088725/remote-debug-jetty-no-mvn-no-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Flex runs in the Flash player which is a web browser plugin. You can connect to the flash player with various debuggers such as fdb, flash builder, intellij.  The swf needs to be compiled for debugging and the flash player needs to be the special flash debug player.